# how to retrieve array from php page to cakephp page?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I retrieve an array which is in one PHP page within one folder or say a project to one CakePHP page within another folder?

I want to generate a graph in a CakePHP page from this array which I want to take from another PHP page .

Comment: What all things have you tried?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Show some of your code!

Answer (score 0):

If that is on same server than you can include that file. If both are on different server than you can use curl for this just like an web service.

Answer (score 0):

Create the array and echo it out in a json format like so

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Then from cakePHP read the array back from the page

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php-page-url"));
```